# iOS HIG for Editing From TableView

Tags: ios, tableview, human-interface

I have a TableView, "events" that segues to another TableView, "attendees". Each has a + (new) button and that works fine. But I'm using a disclosure triangle to indicate that there is more. In the case of "attendees", it's details about the attendee. In the case of "events" it's the list of attendees.

My question is, what is the Apple-recommended (or you-recommended) way of editing an entry in the "events" table, given that touch segues to attendees. I considered using detail-disclosure, but that seemed a bit clunky.

Does anything come to mind or is there a good place for further reading about multi-level hierarchies like this? Note: swipe-left to edit is not enough of a hint for my users. They just won't find it reliably.

Thanks

Comment: I think detail disclosure buttons are fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think the that the scope of the second table could logically be expanded to "Event details" instead of just "Attendees."  In that model, I would envision two sections: one for the event info and one for the attendees.  Here I'm using "sections" loosely--you could use two sections of the same UITableView, or two tables, or even some other arrangement of UI elements for the event info positioned above your existing attendees table.

If you want to allow editing of the event details, you can add a segue to an "edit event" view controller or even edit in place (say, with UITextFields).  Any existing functionality of viewing/editing/adding attendees can be kept in place.

This is definitely a case where there's more than one "right" way to do it, so find a way that looks good and makes sense in the context of your particular app.

Answer (score 0):

In this situation I would refer you to the way Safari allows you to both edit and follow bookmarks. The paradigm that your users are being taught by Apple is to expect to see a single edit button for an entire list. Now whether or not your users are figuring that out is uncertain as people have felt the need to make YouTube videos explaining how it works. Nothing you do is going to satisfy everyone. But, you are pretty much cleared of any wrongdoing when you can say "I did it exactly the way Apple did it in their ... app."

You can [see the bookmarks/edit here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=jV6fTcQl3xU#t=50).